# React Leaflet: How to get access to the Map object after first render?

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a parent component with two children:

1. a Leaflet map
2. a list of locations visible on the map (calculated using the map's getBounds())

I'm having a problem initializing that list of locations. Some things I tried:

- I create a reference using `useRef` in the parent of the two components and passing it the MapContainer via the `ref` tag but it isn't initialized by the time the parent's useEffect happens.
- I created a callback which I tried calling in `whenReady` to pass the bounds back to the parent, but `whenReady` doesn't have access to the Map Object.
- I created a child of the `MapContainer` to handle events. That child reacts to `'load'` and `'moveend'` and that works for when the map moves but doesn't run on first render.
- I tried having the event handler component call a callback in the parent to trigger the redraw. But that causes a component update during a component update which isn't allowed.

So how do I trigger a callback in the parent with the bounds of the map after it is finished loading?